# Convert.ToDateTime not correctly parsing month

Tags: c#

I'm parsing an XML file in C# and for each node I have the following element

```xml
<pubDate>Tue, 08 Dec 2015 13:55:35 +0000</pubDate>
```

I've used `Convert.ToDateTime` to parse it into a date time object, but when I format it out as a string the month aspect of the date is incorrect. For the above element, when I print to the console with the following:

```
 public override string ToString()
    {
        return String.Format("{0} : {2} : {3:dddd dd/mmmm/yyyy HH:mm:ss} : {4}", title, description, guid, date, category);
    }
```

I get the following on the console

> Tuesday 08/55/2015 13:55:35

Every aspect of the date is correct except for the month. I've looked at the `IFormatProvider` but it doesn't seem to be the issue. Any ideas?

Comment: Did you notice that the month number is equal to the minutes? Try using uppercase `M`'s for the month.

Comment: Your string.Format() does not have a {1}, just a 0,2,3,4, although you are passing five replacement values.

Comment: Should look like this : return String.Format("{0} : {1} : {2} : {3} : {4}", title, description, guid, date.ToString("dddd dd/MMMM/yyyy HH:mm:ss"), category);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's in how you've created the format string. `mmmm` translates into minutes. You might consider using `MM` instead, like so:
`dddd dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss`.

Here's some more info on formatting:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 1):

Use `MMM` for month abbreviated name. `m` is only minutes. Refer to [the documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

Month is uppercase M, minutes lower case m. I think mmmm is giving you minutes.

Comment: Yes. Stupid oversight on my part.